# Hello I am new to electric work. I got these Halo Ultra thin downlight direct ceiling mounts and I need help installing them

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling, led

The problem is the hole in the ceiling is 7 inch and it doesn't quite fit. Is there anything I can buy to help make it fit the hole in the ceiling or what can I do to make it fit in the hole.

Comment: Can you provide some pictures of your lights?

Comment: Is the hole too big or too small?

Comment: 7” hole with 6”  lights ? What is the issue.

Comment: 7" hole with 8" lights? See, too many possible problems with the very minimal amount of info you've shared. Please [edit] your post to give some more details and someone (or two or three) will give you some direction.